# persist future values from measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a measure which displays number of employees in relation to the date.
Each day the `FactEmployee` is updated to reflect who is working. this means that my measure (obviously) can't display how many employees there are tomorrow.
I would like to persist the latest value (ie. todays value) into the future.

**Data model**

[image: Data model]

**My (not perfect) measure**

```
Count, employee :=
VAR today = TODAY()
VAR res =
    IF (
        MAX ( DimDate[fulldate] ) > today,
        CALCULATE (
            COUNT ( DimEmployee[emp_key] ),
            FILTER ( ALL ( FactEmployee ), RELATED ( DimDate[fulldate] ) = today)
        ),
        CALCULATE ( COUNT ( DimEmployee[emp_key] ), FactEmployee )
    )
RETURN
    res
```

**Output**

```
 year-month     count, emp      
 ---------------------------
 2020-01        182
 2020-02        180
 2020-03        174
 2020-04        171
 2020-05        171
 2020-06        173
 2020-07        172
 2020-08        175
 2020-09        172
```

**Expected Output**

```
 year-month     count, emp
 --------------------------
 2020-01        182
 2020-02        180
 2020-03        174
 2020-04        171
 2020-05        171
 2020-06        173
 2020-07        172
 2020-08        175
 2020-09        172
 2020-10        172   <----repeated value from 2020-09
 2020-11        172   <----repeated value from 2020-09
 2020-12        172   <----repeated value from 2020-09
```

how can i fix my measure to get the missing values (oktober to december)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replicated your model using a simplified version, I don't think you need `dimEmployee` in this case.

Assuming your model is like this

[image]

And your tables look like these:

```
FactEmployee
+----------+---------+
| date_key | emp_key |
+----------+---------+
| 20200101 | 1       |
+----------+---------+
| 20200102 | 1       |
+----------+---------+
| 20200103 | 1       |
+----------+---------+
| 20200104 | 1       |
+----------+---------+
| 20200105 | 1       |
+----------+---------+
| 20200101 | 2       |
+----------+---------+
| 20200102 | 2       |
+----------+---------+
| 20200104 | 2       |
+----------+---------+
| 20200101 | 3       |
+----------+---------+
| 20200102 | 3       |
+----------+---------+
| 20200103 | 3       |
+----------+---------+
| 20200104 | 3       |
+----------+---------+
| 20200105 | 4       |
+----------+---------+
```

```
DimDate
+------------+----------+
|    Date    | Date_key |
+------------+----------+
| 01/01/2020 | 20200101 |
+------------+----------+
| 02/01/2020 | 20200102 |
+------------+----------+
| 03/01/2020 | 20200103 |
+------------+----------+
| 04/01/2020 | 20200104 |
+------------+----------+
| 05/01/2020 | 20200105 |
+------------+----------+
| 06/01/2020 | 20200106 |
+------------+----------+
| 07/01/2020 | 20200107 |
+------------+----------+
```

I have created a calculation that follow these steps:

1. Compute the maximum date with valid or non blank values for the distinct count of `emp key`, under the variable `MaxDateKey`.
2. `IF` statement evaluated for `date_key` greater than 'MaxDatekey' - in this case `20200106` and `20200107`. For those dates, the calculation retrieves the distinct count of `emp_key` for `MaxDateKey`.
3. When the IF stamenet is false, distinct count is calculated as usual.

```
Count = 
VAR MaxDateKey =
    CALCULATE (
        LASTNONBLANK ( FactEmployee[date_key], DISTINCTCOUNT ( FactEmployee[emp_key] ) ),
        REMOVEFILTERS ( DimDate[Date] )
    )
VAR Result =
    IF (
        MAX ( DimDate[Date_key] ) > MaxDateKey,
        CALCULATE (
            DISTINCTCOUNT ( FactEmployee[emp_key] ),
            ALL ( DimDate[Date] ),
            DimDate[Date_key] = MaxDateKey
        ),
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( FactEmployee[emp_key] )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

The output below. The values from the last valid date 5th of Jan is applied to the subsequent dates (6th and 7th of Jan).

[image]

Comment: this looks interesting, it is not quite right. but i think i can adapt it to my problem. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: after a lot of tinkering, i got it working. 
since my real datamodel is a bit more complex, and i have a lot of other filters/relationships which affects the measure, i needed to change a bit in the formulas. but the basic solution in your answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

For **line chart**, you can check the **Forecast** option from the **Analytics** pane as shown below.

[image]

The output will be something like below-

[image]

Comment: thanks for the repy. i know about the forcast option, but that is not my end goal. i need that measure for another measure.

Comment: Then I did not understand your requirement/logic clearly for those missing 3 values.

Comment: you are right. my question was not that clear :-) i've tried to make it more clear.

Comment: Do you wants something like - fill the value from previous available month if the current value is NULL or BLANK?

Comment: Where from year-month coming from? same table or calendar table?